# How to fix: Error creating bean with name : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field in springboot+mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

> WARN 12700 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mycontroller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in file [D:\Tool\Editor\ideaIu\workplace\toWord\target\classes\com\example\toword\mapper\UserMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/baomidou/mybatisplus/autoconfigure/MybatisPlusAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy

**UserController**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService service;

@RequestMapping("/queryAlluser")
   public List<User> queryalluser() {
      List<User> list = service.queryAlluser();
      return list;
   }
}
```

**UserMapper**

```
@Mapper
@Component
public interface UserMapper {
      List<User> queryAlluser();
}
```

**UerService**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
  @Autowired
  private UserMapper userMapper;
  public List<User> queryAlluser(){
    return userMapper.queryAlluser();
  }
}
```

**UserMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.toword.mapper.UserMapper">
  <select id="queryAlluser" resultType="com.example.toword.entity.User">
     select *
     from user
  </select>
</mapper>
```

I hava added @MapperScan(basePackages ="com.example.toword.mapper") in SpringBootApplication.
And have configurated mapper-location in application.yml as follows.

```
mybatis:
  mapper-locations: classpath:com.example.toword.mapper/*.xml
  configuration:
     map-underscore-to-camel-case: true
```

[image]

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` -- That's a runtime error, not a compilation one. You sucessfully compiled with the library in the classpth, but are trying to run the app without it in the classpath. Please include the command line you are using to start the app.

Comment: oh! yes, i found that my <dependency > about spring-jdbc's scope was test .  Omg, I'm so stupid .